# Encode LINEAR16 audio to Twilio media audio/x-mulaw | NodeJS

Tags: node.js, twilio, google-text-to-speech, mu-law

I have been trying to stream mulaw media stream back to Twilio. Requirement is payload must be encoded audio/x-mulaw with a sample rate of 8000 and base64 encoded

My input is from @google-cloud/text-to-speech in LINEAR16 [Google Docs](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/text/synthesize#audioconfig)

I tried [Wavefile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavefile)

**This is how I encoded the response from @google-cloud/text-to-speech**

```
 const wav = new wavefile.WaveFile(speechResponse.audioContent)
    wav.toBitDepth('8')
    wav.toSampleRate(8000)
    wav.toMuLaw()
```

**Then I send the result back to Twilio via WebSocket**

```
twilioWebsocket.send(JSON.stringify({
      event: 'media',
      media: {
        payload: wav.toBase64(),
      },
      streamSid: meta.streamSid,
}))
```

> Problem is we only hear random noise on other ends of Twilio call, seems like encoding is not proper

> Secondly I have checked the @google-cloud/text-to-speech output audio by saving it in a file and it was proper and clear

> Can anyone please help me with the encoding

Answer (score 6):

I also had this same problem. The error is in `wav.toBase64()`, as this includes the wav header. Twilio media streams expects raw audio data, which you can get with `wav.data.samples`, so your code would be:

```
 const wav = new wavefile.WaveFile(speechResponse.audioContent)
    wav.toBitDepth('8')
    wav.toSampleRate(8000)
    wav.toMuLaw()

 const payload = Buffer.from(wav.data.samples).toString('base64');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same Problem. The solution is, that you need to convert the LINEAR16 by hand to the corresponding MULAW Codec.

You can use the code from [a music libary](https://github.com/dpwe/dpwelib/blob/master/ulaw.c).

I created a function out of this to convert a linear16 byte array to mulaw:

```
short2ulaw(b: Buffer): Buffer {
    // Linear16 to linear8 -> buffer is half the size
    // As of LINEAR16 nature, the length should ALWAYS be even
    const returnbuffer = Buffer.alloc(b.length / 2)

    for (let i = 0; i < b.length / 2; i++) {
      // The nature of javascript forbids us to use 16-bit types. Every number is
      // A double precision 64 Bit number.
      let short = b.readInt16LE(i * 2)

      let sign = 0

      // Determine the sign of the 16-Bit byte
      if (short < 0) {
        sign = 0x80
        short = short & 0xef
      }

      short = short > 32635 ? 32635 : short

      const sample = short + 0x84
      const exponent = this.exp_lut[sample >> 8] & 0x7f
      const mantissa = (sample >> (exponent + 3)) & 0x0f
      let ulawbyte = ~(sign | (exponent << 4) | mantissa) & 0x7f

      ulawbyte = ulawbyte == 0 ? 0x02 : ulawbyte

      returnbuffer.writeUInt8(ulawbyte, i)
    }

    return returnbuffer
  }
```

Now you could use this on Raw PCM (Linear16). Now you just need to consider to strip the bytes at the beginning of the google stream since google adds a wav header.
You can then encode the resulting base64 buffer and send this to twilio.